# Testing installing a newly built R package and its dependencies

Tags: r, installation, package

I have just created a Rpackage in RStudio, built it and installed into the same R version. Basically I have pressed the "*Build and reload the package (Ctrl + Shift + B)*" button. By this method I get the package installed in the same R version, so that `library(mypackage)` works directly and I can use my own package in another RSession.

However, I would like to pass the package for others to be used and test that all package dependencies work as desired. Therefore, I have invoked "*Build binary package*" in order to have package `mypackage_{version_number}.zip`.

**What is the preferred way to test the installing of a newly created binary package and, especially, its dependencies?**

My primary environment has all dependencies installed, therefore, `Imports:` clausus in `DEPENDENCIES` file seem to have no effect. The installing of all necessary dependencies is exactly what I would like to test.

I found the idea of trying to install the package into another R version. However, in that case I could test the dependencies only once, because all the dependencies (hopefully) get installed to that R version when installing the package and its dependencies first time.

Comment: check out travis ci: http://jtleek.com/protocols/travis_bioc_devel/

Comment: @clemens: Is travis bound to GitHub? I am looking for a solution which I could use in my own computer.

Answer (score 0):

If Travis is not an option, you could test your package using win builder (http://win-builder.r-project.org/) through `devtools::build_win()`.

Make sure to add the maintainer role in authors in the `DESCRIPTION` of your package, because win builder will send an email once the tests are completed.

Comment: According to the above link, it is suggested to upload the data into a server (ftp : //win-builder.r-project.org/), whereas I am looking for an offline solution.